# Problem with JSON extractor and nested fields

Tags: graylog

I have an issue with JSON fields not extracted properly.

First of all I have an JSON Extractor on my input that extracts the message field, this will result in a new MESSAGE field, with the following contents:

{"kind":"Event","apiVersion":"audit.k8s.io/v1","level":"Metadata","auditID":"e03a5c76-2122-4c1d-8265-be6e9cdc5e11","stage":"ResponseComplete","requestURI":"/api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/configmaps/ingress-controller-leader-nginx","verb":"update","user":{"username":"system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx:ingress-nginx","uid":"42491580-cda5-4856-9f1b-ae133faadba7","groups":["system:serviceaccounts","system:serviceaccounts:ingress-nginx","system:authenticated"]},"sourceIPs":["10.81.100.2"],"userAgent":"nginx-ingress-controller/v0.40.2 (linux/amd64) ingress-nginx/fc4ccc5eb0e41be2436a978b01477fc354f31643","objectRef":{"resource":"configmaps","namespace":"ingress-nginx","name":"ingress-controller-leader-nginx","uid":"7bd1f348-9586-45ea-b41c-897c8ba83985","apiVersion":"v1","resourceVersion":"178373"},"responseStatus":{"metadata":{},"code":200},"requestReceivedTimestamp":"2020-11-04T09:21:18.756400Z","stageTimestamp":"2020-11-04T09:21:18.759305Z","**annotations":{"authentication.k8s.io/legacy-token":"system:serviceaccount:ingress-nginx:ingress-nginx","authorization.k8s.io/decision":"allow","authorization.k8s.io/reason":"RBAC: allowed by RoleBinding "ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx" of Role "ingress-nginx" to ServiceAccount "ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx""}**}

But then the issue is that the JSON path annotations (in bold) is not extracted into fields. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because `annotations` and more specifically `authorization.k8s.io/reason`'s property value breaks the JSON format.